# How to find longest route between two location via Google directions api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am using google direction api to find route between two points. It is currently returning me shortest available route between two points. Is there is anyway to find the longest route between two point using google direction apis.

Comment: how u find route between two points? (code)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by longest route?! you can pass all the streets in the continent you are in and still don't reach the destination!

For example you want to go from Norway to Sweden and you go to Denmark and keep moving in streets forever :D

Comment: I don't get it client just want to get longest route I am also still wandering? :0

Comment: maybe by longest they mean longest route between 3 routes that Google Maps recommends.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you need to use Direction API instead of Distance Matrix API.
Please note that you need to add alternatives=true to your query parametrs, then you will have all possible routes suggest by google maps, in addition to their distances/durations :-)